# navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() Returns Only Partial Data

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

I am trying to get all the video devices that are on the phone. I then want to load up one of the cameras through the "video" tag.

I am having a weird problem where certain devices do not give me all the information though.

On my phone (moto g6 (chrome), Samsung A50 (Samsung browser & chrome) I get all the information such as DeviceId and Device Label.

On my ipad mini (safari) and on a Samsung A70 (chrome) I am missing that information.

```
   if(navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia){
      navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
      .then(function(devices) {
        devices.forEach(function(device) {
           display(device);
        });
      })
    }

 function display(obj) {
    var res = "";
    for (var a in obj) {
      res += a + ": " + obj[a] + "\n";
    }
    alert(res);
  }
```